# Using a While loop to assign array values generates "Index outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

Okay, this is a completely noob question.  Brace yourself.

I'm attempting to use a While loop to assign values to an array, and I'm getting an Index outside bounds of array error message.  Here's what it looks like:

```
int [] Counter = new int [46];

xCount = 0;
while (xCount != 47)
{
    Counter[xCount] = (xCount * 10000);
    xCount++;   
}
```

Should I be using different C# code to set values in the array?
Thanks in advance for any answers/insight!

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(...).Select(x=>x*10000).ToArray()`? (Although, why an array at all?). You can write loops if you want to, but why not use the modern framework and concentrate on solving problems instead?

Comment: Originally I was setting them individually as Counter1, Counter2, etc.  I was attempting to experiment with arrays to see if they'd be more efficient.  

Care to elaborate on what you mean by a 'modern framework'?

Comment: Why 47?? You declared array with 46 cells..

Comment: Loop conditions other than `index < array.Length` are suspicious and should be handled carefully to avoid doing them wrong, such as the off-by-one here..

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz - Yep!  Per another comment below, I totally spaced that discrepancy.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @harold - Noted.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Counter = Enumerable.Range(0,47).Select(x=>x*10000).ToArray();
```

Should give you an array of 47 elements. It uses the [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects) [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

But, stop and ask yourself whether an array is the best thing to be using (for whatever problem you're trying to solve). There are modern [collection classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/when-to-use-generic-collections) that are better suited for most problems than arrays are. In general, unless you're writing a collection class yourself or needing to interoperate with older code, I'd suggest steering clear of array.

Also, note that the code above is *declarative*. I'm saying *what I want*, without worrying about the details of *how it's done*. Behind the scenes, maybe it's using a loop, or some other mechanism to generate that range; but I don't really care about that, I just want to start with that range, apply a transformation (via select) and then force it into an array. I also don't care what it's using to *store* that range/calculation during the intermediate stages.

There are still places where loops are appropriate - but writing a `while` loop and incrementing a counter is somewhat odd. The standard idiom for iterating over an array would be a `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<Counter.Length;i++)
{
     Counter[i] = i*10000;
}
```

Note also how I'm using the length of the array rather than hard-coding a number. This ensures that we don't go off the end of the array. **The error in your code** is actually related to this. When you write `new int [46]` you're creating an array with 46 elements. That means that the valid indexes into this array are 0-45. Your loop attempts to use [index 46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), which as the exception complained, was outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Yes, an array always commences from zero. So, Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer is right.

Comment: Great explanation and description Damien!  Your answer was perfect.  Thank you very much for taking the time to respond with a heavily detailed/explained answer.  I really appreciate it.  I'll move forward without the while loops and follow your guidance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: indexes in C# start from 0, so number of elements will be **always greater by 1 than last index of an array**! I.e: you have 2 elements, indexes: 0 and 1.

Your case: you initialized array with 46 elements, then your indexes are in range 0-45.

Comment: Hi Michal, you're absolutely right.  When I woke up and looked at the example I posted, I immediately thought the same thing.  I had been starting at too much code during the day yesterday and I totally spaced it.  Thank you for pointing that out and taking the time to post a reply. :)

Comment: Hi @Spiderbird , if my answer helped you, you should accept it and optionally upvote :)